Does Windows 11 backup require Windows to restore the files?
For the last 20 years, I've ignored Windows backup entirely and disabled the service because in those days, if you backed up a file with Windows backup, it compressed it into a weird format.
I figured maybe I should take another look at Windows backup, but not if I'm going to get it into another proprietary hell upon file restore.
So, does Windows 11 backup require Windows to restore the files?

The format has not changed.

If the deletion of this single question prevented you from asking new questions it means you were rate limited or question banned. It doesn’t mean you are stupid or are a troll, it means, you are new so you can’t asked multiple questions at once to avoid flooding our community or have asked questions in the past which were not well received. You have a single question that wasn’t received that hasn’t been deleted so I am guessing those other questions were deleted since your profile appears to be established enough where a rate limit isn’t necessary.

Asking a question then deleting the question isn’t positive behavior. If you submit a question you have to stick with it and improve it until it’s well received and can be answered

Are you referring to Windows Backup, which uses OneDrive, or Windows Backup and Restore (Windows 7), which uses a VHD?

@JW0914 the latter. ty.

@MissUnderstands - 3 deleted questions is significant number of questions, most users have 0 questions, deleted.

@MissUnderstands Windows Backup and Restore is a really poor solution, instead use Dism to capture a WIM, which can contain multiple backups in a single file - I go into detail about why Windows Backup and Restore isn't a solution that should be used by anyone under Is the native method generally the best method for most users? WIMs are superior to Windows Backup and Restore in every way, with the added benefit you gain parity.

@JW0914 Parity? Is error detection really an issue these days? And I certainly hope compression isn't an issue any more.

@MissUnderstands Please read the relevant section within the answer I linked to, which will explain in detail. Data verification [parity] is important when restoring, and WBR does little, if any, compression. If you're looking for a native backup/restore solution, WIMs are the way to go and are the same solution Microsoft has used for decades to deploy Windows onto a machine (it's also what WinRE and an install USB boots from). The answer linked to is the most comprehensive answer one will come across for WIMs, and the comparison to WBR is done under the aforementioned section.

Windows File Backup is still proprietary. Best option with Windows might be File History to an external drive, or using a third party option.

Windows Backup is a really poor solution and isn't proprietary AFAIK (it creates a VHD & catalog files, and uses VSS to copy data over), and File History while better, lacks compression and parity. Instead, Dism can be used to capture a WIM, which can contain multiple backups in a single file - I go into detail about why Windows Backup isn't a solution that should be used by anyone under Is the native method generally the best method for most users? WIMs are superior to Windows Backup in every way, with the added benefit of gaining parity.
